# Amazon EC2 | CodeDeploy [React] - Deployment succeeds but build folder not populated

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

TL;DR The command `npm run build` is taking forever to run on the Amazon EC2 [Ubuntu] instance when I tried running it explicitly by making an SSH. Meanwhile, when I try to create a deployment using CodeDeploy, the deployment takes a good 1 hour time and succeeds but the build folder doesn't get populated, hence I am unable to view my website on the public URL of the EC2 instance. Also, the instance reachability check fails every time after I try to run the command explicitly, and then I have to start and then stop the ec2 instance again! Woof!

---

Hello everyone, I am trying to deploy my MERN Stack application to AWS but I am stuck now!

Current Progress:

1. Added both Nginx configs.[Attaching image below]
   Nginx is running and there is no problem there!
2. Added build-app.sh in appspec.yml in the root directory. [View code below]

```
#!/bin/bash

#clear  build    directory
cd /home/ubuntu/badlav-app/badlav-client
sudo rm -rf build
sudo mkdir build

#client (Generates a new `build` directory)
cd /home/ubuntu/badlav-app/badlav-client
sudo sh set-prod-env-aws.sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules
sudo npm i
sudo npm run build

#server
cd /home/ubuntu/badlav-app/badlav-server
sudo sh set-prod-env.sh

#back to root
cd /home/ubuntu
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/badlav-app
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/build-app.sh
      runas: root
```

Using the above appspec.yml file, the deployment using CodeDeploy succeeds but didn't populate the build folder within `/home/badlav-app/badlav-client/build`.
So I tried to debug on my own and started running the commands one by one by myself after SSH(ing :P) into the EC2 instance. But when I reach `npm run build`, the instance just hangs forever. After being exhausted, I have no option left, I terminate the task. Now, when I view my instance on the AWS Console, it has gone berserk! The instance reachability check fails! The only way, I get my instance back is by stopping it and starting it again.

Since I am new to CI/CD, please don't judge my `appspec.yml`. It'd be great if anyone of you could suggest a better way, thanks for that! :)

To sum up, I want to be able to create a deployment using AWS CodeDeploy, but due to this `npm run build` taking so much time and hanging my server(instance reach check fails!), I am unable to do so. Moreover, I am not even sure whether `npm run build` is a problem at all!

I would be more than happy to share any further details/screenshots in order to support my question. Please ask over.

Thanks in advance!

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf[image]/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
[image: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf]

Comment: Can you show  your `appspec.yml` file?

Comment: Edited, added it. Please find. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using EC2 free tier, the chance is that the instance may have low spec and memory (`t2.nano` has 0.5G and `t2.micro` has 1G of memory).

Maybe `npm run build` consumes all of the memory space.

I often face the same problem with my vue project.

Solution: Do NOT use free tier for medium and large projects. Upgrade your plan and use better instances e.g. `t2.medium`

Comment: Oh, I was not fully aware of that: Maybe this is what it is. How do you build then?

Comment: Please let me know, I have t2.micro

Comment: I upgraded to t2.medium. It worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Could you also please try to answer this, I am stuck again, sorry!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317832/aws-unable-to-make-api-calls-to-ec2-server-via-application-load-balancer-alb